# What are the practical differences between solder balls and spherical tin powder?

Tags: conductivity, solder-paste

Solder balls are made of tin, with small amounts of silver and copper. The minimum size of solder balls is limited. Nano spherical tin powder is available in smaller particle sizes. If such a tin powder were placed between conductive objects, and melted in the same way solder balls are, is there any reason why this would not also form a conductive pathway between objects?

Comment: It's not "small amounts of silver and copper". You can actually read the composition on every package of solder balls. Or on product pages!

Comment: Metallurgy thrives on the large effect of seemingly small additions. Changes in decimel percentages have tangible effects.

Comment: Tin alone doesn't make great solder, though it is workable as such. The best solders for electrical work are about 60% tin and 40% lead, but to limit lead use most solders nowadays are about 95~97% tin, 3~4% silver, and 0.5~1% copper. The highest tin content in a commonly used solder might be in SN100C, which is 99.2% tin, 0.7% copper, with tiny amounts of nickel (0.06%) and germanium (0.005%). The nickel and germanium are actually quite important to the alloy, despite how tiny an amount there is in there!

Comment: @Hearth I got a roll of SN100C I have yet to use because I was curious about the marketing about germanium

Comment: @DKNguyen I've been using it for a while; got it for the same reason. As a wire solder, it's about on par with SAC305, though it does indeed produce shinier joints--the marketing to that effect, at least, wasn't exaggerated. It's still a lead-free solder, though, so it's still rather annoying to work with compared to the leaded stuff.

Comment: SN100C is good choice for SMD rework. Aside from higher temperature it's pretty similar to 60/40 in feel and appearance.

Answer (score 2):

There are solder balls (as on BGA = Ball Grid Array) packages and there are the balls of solder in solder paste.

The first are relatively large diameter (a fraction of a mm) and the latter are typically quite small (20-40um typically, the exact range will be specified directly or by mesh number).

Anyway, depending on what you are planning to use it for the [optimum alloy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solder_alloys) may be different- metallurgy is complex (and cost factors are at play). For example, BGAs are subject to forces from thermal cycling so the brittleness/ductility of the solder may affect the reliability and product lifetime. Dendrites/whiskers can form, particularly in the presence of moisture, and that can cause premature failures. "Creep" can be a factor. Flux that is appropriately active is essential to get the solder to 'wet' the surfaces being attached, but it also should be inactive enough under normal conditions to be left after soldering or should be easy to remove in a cleaning operation. Solder paste contains the tiny balls in a matrix of flux (easy to see under a microscope, but it just looks like a gray paste from afar).

Anyway, I would suggest getting actual solder and flux if you want to solder something reliably. 63/37 SnPb (eutectic alloy) solder is wonderful stuff, but more toxic than is ideal. The Wikipedia article I linked lists a fairly large number of alloys and their pluses and minuses.

Answer (score 1):

> If such a tin powder were placed between conductive objects, and melted in the same way solder balls are, is there any reason why this would not also form a conductive pathway between objects?

yeah, surface tension and oxidation. You would need to suspend these tiny particles in solder flux, essentially.

Coincidentally, that's *exactly* what solder paste is.

Comment: thank you. If I were using a vacuum oven to melt solder powder, would I still need flux to deal with oxidation?

Comment: Yes, to break the already existing oxide, and because of surface tension.